# hiding/showing specific column according to permission

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I need to hide/show action columns based on permissions
if action column is null I want to hide action column, if action has data I want to show that data passes on backend side.

```
// my backend code php
$data = $this->userModal->userslist();
foreach($data as $d){
if(ChechPermission($this->session->userdata('permissions'), "users", "edit")) {
$d->actions ='
<a href="Users/edit/'.$d->userid.'" class="btn btn-success btn-md"><i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i></a>
';
} else {
$d->actions = '';
}


}
echo json_encode($data); 
// end backend code php
```

```
// my datatable

$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $("#userTable").dataTable({
 
        pageLength: 25,
        lengthMenu: [25, 50, 75, 100],
         "dom": '<"top"lfB>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
 
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
 
 
 
        'ajax' : {'url' : 'Users/getusers' , dataSrc : ""},
 
        columns : [
 
 
            {data : 'firstname'},
            {data : 'middlename'},
            {data : 'lastname'},
            {data : 'username'},
            {data : 'mobileno'},
            {data : 'statusname'},
            {data : 'groupname'},
            {data : 'actions'}
 
 
        ]
    });
});
```

my expected code in the datatable is a condition that filters action column data

Answer (score 0):

Hi Abdir Abdirahim Ali,

There is a **visible** property which accept `boolean`.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible

Here is a example for you.

Your frontend:

```
let showActionColumn= "<?= $showActionColumn ?>";    
columns : [
        {data : 'firstname'},
        {data : 'middlename'},
        {data : 'lastname'},
        {data : 'username'},
        {data : 'mobileno'},
        {data : 'statusname'},
        {data : 'groupname'},
        {data : 'actions', visible : showActionColumn}
    ]
```

Your backend:

```
$data['showActionColumn'] = ChechPermission($this->session->userdata('permissions'), "users", "edit")
```

Comment: returns nothing

Comment: Chee Chong Tay 
your idea is so close but could you explain the backend code and where i will put inside my code

Comment: Hi bro, you should put in your controller when you bring the data to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Using `columnDefs` can be useful for your case :

```
$('#userTable').DataTable({
        pageLength: 25,
        lengthMenu: [25, 50, 75, 100],
        "dom": '<"top"lfB>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        'ajax' : {'url' : 'Users/getusers' , dataSrc : ""},
        columns : [
            {data : 'firstname'},
            {data : 'middlename'},
            {data : 'lastname'},
            {data : 'username'},
            {data : 'mobileno'},
            {data : 'statusname'},
            {data : 'groupname'},
            {data : 'actions'}
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 7, // column assigned in the html table
                "render": function(data, type, row) {
                    let _data = '';
                    if (row['actions'] != '') {     
                        _data = row['actions'] ;
                    }
                    return _data;
                }
            },
        ]
    });
```

Comment: still it does not work

Comment: Can you share the result of your Ajax Users/getusers ?

Comment: {
    "userid": "209",
    "firstname": "CABDIKARIIM",
    "middlename": "MAXAMED",
    "lastname": "ISMAACIIL",
    "username": "ssm3074",
    "mobileno": "9633022431",
    "emailaddress": "9633022431@nomail.com",
    "usertypeid": "2",
    "statusname": "active",
    "groupname": "SALES",
    "actions": ""
}

Comment: Can you recheck again, I have made a small update in my response